# How define LaTeX command with 2 or 3 arguments in comma-separated list

Tags: macros, xparse, optional-arguments, comma-separated-list

To avoid typing subscripts and extra parentheses and brackets, I want to define a command, say `\disk`, that may be used with a comma-separated list of either 2 or 3 arguments, like this:

```
$\disk{r,x}$
$\disk{r,x,d}$
```

that will produce, respectively, the same output as would directly typing:

```
$D_{r}(x)$
$D_{r}(x;d)$
```

[The `r`, `x`, and `d` could, of course, by any letter or number, etc. For example, I might use `\disk{\epsilon, 0, D}`, etc.]

Using `xparse` or otherwise, how might this be done?

Although I am aware that the two different outputs could be obtained by using an optional argument, that would require typing the 3rd, optional argument inside brackets; and in any case even for the case of only two arguments, I want to speed up typing by using just the comma-separated list `{x, d}` rather than `{x}{d}`.

Answer (score 5):

We can do this at TeX primitive level without any `xparse` or another package.
Note, there are only two lines of code.

```
\def\disk#1{\diskA#1,,\end}
\def\diskA#1,#2,#3,#4\end{D_{#1}\ifx,#3,(#2)\else (#2;#3)\fi}

$\disk{r,x}$

$\disk{r,x,s}$

\end
```

If you need to do something like this `$\disk{\epsilon,(1,2),\rho}$` then add one line of code:

```
\def\disk#1{\diskA#1()\end}
\def\diskA#1(#2)#3\end{\ifx\end#3\end\diskB#1,,\end \else\diskA#1{(#2)}#3\end \fi}
\def\diskB#1,#2,#3,#4\end{D_{#1}\ifx,#3,(#2)\else (#2;#3)\fi}

$\disk{r,x}$

$\disk{r,x,s}$

$\disk{\epsilon,(1,2),\rho}$

\end
```

Comment: Hard now for me to choose which answer to accept: your pure TeX method is nicely terse, yet the more complicated LaTeX (with `xparse`) seemingly leaves things at the higher level of abstraction that avoids TeX primitives. Wish I could accept both!

Answer (score 4):

You have to assume there are three items; if there aren't, the missing ones are automatically passed to the inner macro as “No Value”.

Then the inner macro can check for the value being given.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\disk}{ >{\SplitArgument{2}{,}} m }{\printdisk#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printdisk}{mmm}{D_{#1}(#2\IfValueT{#3}{;#3})}

\begin{document}

$\disk{r,x}$

$\disk{r,x,s}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\disk}{m}
 {
  % split the input at commas
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_murray_disk_input_seq { , } { #1 }
  % remove the leftmost item
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_murray_disk_input_seq \l_murray_disk_radius_tl
  % print; _ is not available here
  D\c_math_subscript_token{\l_murray_disk_radius_tl}
    (\seq_use:Nn \l_murray_disk_input_seq { ; })
 }
\seq_new:N \l_murray_disk_input_clist
\tl_new:N \l_murray_disk_radius_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\disk{r,x}$

$\disk{r,x,s}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: However, typing `$D_{r}(x;s)$` seems easier

Comment: Not easier to type for me! Without the macro, the direct way requires a separate finger reach for `_` and either typing the pair of braces around the subscript or else (in TeXShop) moving the cursor beyond the automatically supplied pair of braces. With the macro, I don't have to stop each time to think whether I want a comma or a semicolon before the 3rd item (the metric), and should I change my mind about that style, I can do it just once, within the macro definition.

Comment: The real trick in the Answer is that `\printdisk` uses the triple-`m` expression `mmm` even when I use `\disk` with only 2 items in the comma-separated list.

Comment: Oops, doesn't work for something like `$\disk{\epsilon,(1,2),\rho}$`. My workaround for that is `$\disk{\epsilon,{(1,2)},\rho}$` -- a slight annoyance of extra braces.

Comment: @murray If you plan to use something like `(1,2)`, then change the delimiter in the argument, say `;`

Comment: @murray No, use `\SplitArgument{2}{;}`

Comment: Any advantage of the 2nd, longer, implementation?